# How to find a place on google map by postal code for specific country

Tags: php, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This method used to work for me before: when I have a postal code, I just add it to the end of the following link:

```
https://www.google.com/maps?q=
```

eg. postal code is 649414 then I can view the location by:

```
https://www.google.com/maps?q=649414
```

But after a while, I recognised that it won't show the right place any more. The reason could be there are several places on the world have the same postal code. So it just show an area (like US) or a different place from what I expected. So if I want to be precise, I need to click another result on the page to choose my region.
My question is, is there any way I could automatically narrow the search for a specific country, say Singapore ? 
If you search for postal code like : 272012 , it will have 2 results at Singapore and Shandong - China. but the link on the address bar is the same:

```
https://www.google.com/maps?q=272012
```

How could I set in my code in php to make it redirect to this page:

```
https://www.google.com/maps?q=272012
```

but only in Singapore ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the location name and "+" before the postal code:

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Singapore+272012

Comment: That is an excellent solution. Btw, in testing I just find out that Google map have an out-of-date location. Like the postal code : Singapore 649414 is not pointing to the right place. Do you know if it is possible to re-locate it on google map ?

Comment: Yes it is. You can see the right location if you post that to http://www.whereto.sg/

Comment: Yes, I made the report. Thank you for great help !